# Global Variables/Functions in Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask and Python and am currently creating a small web app. The files it has are: Main (Just runs the app), Activate, Checkout, Payment.

I have a bunch of redundant code and variables throughout the 3 other pages such as:

- A function verifying a Shopify webhook
- Generating the "Credentials" portion of a post XML to a different API (Can make into a function)
- Some credentials variables for this API: ID, username, password, pin, referenceNumber, etc.
- Google Sheets API credential variables

Would I be able to just put the functions and variables inside Main.py and just import it to the other 3 files? Would that be good practice? Would it be a problem if some of those other files would access a variable or function from Main at the same time? For example: Checkout and Payment may somehow be accessing the verifyShopifyWebhook() function at the same time since they are run when Shopify sends a webhook to either address.

I also have a bunch of the same imports on Activate, Checkout and Refund. Can I just put the same ones all under Main and import them from Main?

Comment: you will probably get circular imports if you put them in main.py ... but you could put the shared code in some `util.py` or something and import it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Credential variables

The general way to use sensitive variable is to store them as enviroment variable. You can save all your credentials variables into a `.env` file at project root:

```
API_ID=my_id
API_USERNAME=my_username
```

Remember to add it into .gitignore:

```
.env
```

Then you can use [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) or something similar to import the variable:

```
# pip install python-dotenv
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

Now you can access this variable in this way:

```
import os

api_id = os.getenv('API_ID')
```

### Redundant code

Just create a `utils.py`, save them as functions.

Comment: Thanks! What about importing modules such as gspread, lxml, json, os, etc.? Would I be able to also put them all in utils.py?

Comment: Just import them in the place you need.